# Exhaustive list of Linux commands for command prompt

Tags: command-line

1. Where does Linux keep the list of valid commands that can be called from the command prompt (using ENTER key after command is typed)?
2. Is this list exhaustive or are there ways to type other things at the command prompt that are NOT in this list; and if so, what are they?  (ie: CTRL+C -- to break from the command prompt, etc)

***If you don't know the answers to those two questions, feel free to answer this instead:***

3. Where does the source code begin on Linux when hitting ENTER at the command line after typing a command?
4. Where does the source code begin on Linux if ANY command is executed at the command prompt?

---

My questions may be user specific based on security, so to keep it simple, let's use user root for brevity.

Comment: Please stop adding new questions. 2 questions is already 1 too many, and you've just added a fourth one after I posted my answer.

Comment: plus, for this to be oriented towards computer security, you seem to be missing a bit of basic theory! Maybe start a bit more basic.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert with computer security.  I'm just trying to understand Linux better for work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere.

Linux is the kernel, and just the kernel. Any commands are either shell built-ins, which are listed in the documentation of each shell, or executable binaries located usually in `/bin` and `/sbin` directories in the `/`, `/usr` and `/usr/local`. Shells themselves are also binaries located in those directories.

There are no limits what binaries are included in a Linux distribution. Certain binaries are considered standard tools (`echo`, `ls`, `grep` etc.) but there are no requirements for any developer to include them.

The last questions make no sense. Source code is what you write to create an executable binary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933620/in-which-directory-is-shell-source-code-and-executable-present

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/512918/how-do-i-list-all-available-shell-builtin-commands

Answer (score 1):

> Where does Linux keep the list of valid commands that can be called from the command prompt?

That's nothing that *Linux* keeps, that's a feature of your *shell*, whichever that might be! But, basically all shells on Linux will look through the directories in the `PATH` environment variable for executables. They also have built-in commands and in most of them, you can also define functions and aliases, which a lot of things do when the shell gets initialized.

So, depending on the shell, and how it's been set up, this will be multiple lists, composed from entries from a list of directories, programmed in commands, and extensions loaded at initialization.

> Is this list exhaustive or are there ways to type other things at the command prompt that are NOT in this list; and if so, what are they?

You've asked for an exhaustive list, and now you're asking whether it's exhaustive… that makes no sense.

> Where does the source code begin on Linux when hitting ENTER at the command line after typing a command?

Again, that's not Linux, that is the shell program you're executing. Specifically, the pressing of <kbd>Enter</kbd> will mean something to an input handling library, which will pass it to an input-tokenizing step, which will pass it on to an input-token-interpreting step, which will pass it on to a translation/execution step.

In the end, your shell is an interpreter for a formal language, and hence, technically, pretty similar to any other compiler.

Comment: "What's the default shell on Linux": no such thing exists. Some distros use bash, other dash, other ash, some busybox…

Comment: Thanks for your answer.